# Manually create a transaction to spend the output of a P2SH tx

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, p2sh

I want to manually create a transaction to spend the output of a P2SH tx, but I don't know where the redeem script should be placed in the new transaction?  I followed an online tutorial [Building a Transaction By Hand](https://klmoney.wordpress.com/bitcoin-dissecting-transactions-part-2-building-a-transaction-by-hand/)

In order to sign the transaction, you need to build this tx message as the picture shows. But when there is a redeem script, where should i put this redeem script?

[image: Transaction Message That Will Be Signed]

Answer (score 0):

The redeem script is part of the scriptSig for the input you are trying to spend. Here is the format for a [`P2SH` transaction](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction#Pay-to-Script-Hash):

```
scriptPubKey: OP_HASH160 <scriptHash> OP_EQUAL 
scriptSig: ..signatures... <serialized script>
```

The script is hashed and compared with the script hash in the `scriptPubKey`.